# ZSSRichTextEditor to be used inside a view having 2-3 webviews

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to integrate the ZSSRichTextEditor inside my view controller. There are about 3-4 textview which I have to update them as HTML editor textview.

As its only available for full view controller.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: What do you have already?

Comment: As per the sample app of "ZSSRichTextEditor" the demo which were present only explains the creation of editor using the subclass of "ZSSRichTextEditor". But i want to use it in my own webview. Can you help?

Comment: I can't, but maybe if you include some code in your question other people might be able to point out what you need.

Comment: https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor

this HTML editor i am using. Can you check if we can integrate this with webview within other class

Comment: I created ZSSRichTextEditor, and it was only ever meant to work as a full view editor. Doing anything else will require some hacking on your part.